# Redirect MATLAB stdout to C++

Tags: c++, matlab

I have a code written in C++ which initiate a MATLAB function. 
I want to redirect MATLAB fprintf and disp that usually goes to console to C++.

I can not change the MATLAB code.
I prefer a real time solution where
I can display progress logs to user while MATLAB is in calculations.

Anybody familiar with how to do that?

Comment: you can run matlab in console mode then all matlab console output goes to the shell

Comment: The mechanism for capturing the Command Window output is through the [engOutputBuffer](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/engoutputbuffer.html) function.  Unfortunately it will only capture the whole output (not line by line, or streaming, as you'd like), and you really need to know what size buffer to create in advance.  AFAIK  there is no work around for this.